# How to make variable stable in Flask app python?

Tags: python, list, flask, server

I'm creating server with flask in python. I have a variable store a list string called `list_names`. Client post request with a name then server will check if this name already exist in list, if not it will save this name to `list_names`. I tested several times by print the list and realize that the `list_names` is unstable, some time the name in list is disappear then reappear.
Here is my code:

```
list_name = ['common']
```

```
self.app.add_url_rule('/add_name', 'add_name', self.add_name_api, methods=['POST'])
```

```
def add_name_api(self):
        name = self.request.form.get('name')
        if name not in list_names:
            list_names.append(name)
            print(list_names)
            return self.response_success('Name %s added' % name)
        else:
            print(list_names)
            return self.response_error('Name %s already exists' % name)
```

Comment: You can not use global variables in Flask. While it will work to some degree in the development server, it will fail in a production setup where you typically have multiple worker processes with one instance of the variable in each.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store something then reuse it you better go for some `databases`. I would suggest you to go for `sqlite3` which is a lite weight database, fast and doesn't require a `server` to run. Python has a builtin module sqlite3 .